# Weakness of Hal Jordan in Justice League: Doom

Tags: character, justice-league-doom

What was the weakness of Hal Jordan aka Green Lantern in the movie *Justice League: Doom* which was exploited by Batman which was used later by Vandal Savage to neutralize or kill him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batman explained it to Hal in the mine after revealing it was all a set-up..

> BATMAN: You were dosed with a synthesized version of the Scarecrow's fear gas....because **will** is the source of your strength.
>
> HAL: And fear is the enemy of will.